# Excel: Autofill (copy) whole row when value is entered in 1st column

Tags: excel, autocomplete, autofill

I am using Excel 2010 and looking for a way to autocomplete the whole row of a table when the unique identifier in the first colum is entered. For example a kind of log book for a warehouse:

Each row of the table contains one item with a unique ID, description, category, prize and date when it was last sold. Every time an item is sold, I add a new row where ID, description and category keep constant but the prize and date varies.
How is it possible to enter the ID in the first column and have the description and category in the second and third column auto-filled if there already exists an older entry for this ID?
Additionally, I would prefer the auto-filled cells to contain values not formulas (so that newer entries for one ID do not change if and older entry for that ID should be changed later on).

I have no clue on VBA but maybe it is possible without? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you dont want formulas and you dont want VBA...maybe magic? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

On Sheet1 you record your sales.
On Sheet2 you maintain your basic data and actual price of every ID:
(A) ID (B) Description (C) Actual Price

I would use the following VBA:

Sub calculation()

```
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:C"), 2, 0)
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:C"), 3, 0)

End Sub
```

If you run the code than in the row of selected (or active cell) the data will be entered.

Solution TWO (without VBA):

You do the smae as above, use Sheet2 for basic data.
Than in Sheet1:

Cell B1: =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:C,2,0)
Cell C1: =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:C,3,0)

When the values are entered you select the lines you entered copy it and paste only the values in the same cells.